# Java interfaces and objects

Tags: java, oop, interface

Over here i'm trying to make use of an interface called "Measurable" with one method called getMeasure. The problem is, I'm trying to get the average height of all the people in my program, by accessing the method in my interface. One of the problems I can't access the getMeasure method for some reason, and at last get the average height of all the people in the array. How can I solve this problem?

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person[] people = new Person[4];
        people[0] = new Person("Larry", 65);
        people[1] = new Person("Susan", 45);
        people[2] = new Person("Joe", -45);
        people[3] = new Person("", 0);
        double averageHeight = average(people);
    }

    public static double average(Person[] objects)
    {
        if (objects.length == 0) { return 0; }
        double sum = 0;
        for (Person obj : objects)
        {
            double measure = obj.getMeasure();
            sum = sum + measure;
        }
        double result = sum / objects.length;
        return result;
    }
}



interface Measurable {
    double getMeasure();
}
```

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer height;



    public Person(String name, Integer height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }


    public double getMeasure() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Comment: You `Person` doesn't implement the `interface`... Make it's declaration `public class Person implements Measurable { ... }`

Comment: Your code should work "as-is", although you dont make use of the `Measurable` interface at all. Please post the exact error you get!

Answer (score 4):

The `Person` class should implement `Measurable`:

```
public class Person implements Measurable {
    ...
}
```

Then if you want to make your `average` function reusable (I guess this is your desired outcome), you should replace the `Person` instance with `Measurable`:

```
public static double average(Measurable[] objects) {
    ...
    for (Measurable obj : objects){
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you could have different `Measurable` implementations to calculate the average.

Comment: Just by calling your function same name as interface function doesn't mean you are overriding it. As explained by Alex you have to implement that interface in order to override it's methods

Comment: Sure, the interface is not used if the OP doesn't implements the interface, however that doesn't really answer the question: "One of the problems I can't access the getMeasure method"

Comment: I was trying to implement the interface and make use of the getMeasure method

Comment: @UMLtotallydistilled is my answer what you intended to use? - trying to guess minds here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person implements Measurable {
private String name;
private Integer height;



public Person(String name, Integer height)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public double getMeasure() {
    return height;
}
```

You have to implement the to use it. If the Interface also implements the method, you have to add the @Override modifier.

Comment: The `@Override` annotation is not mandatory in this case. It should work without it, as long as the class `implements` the interface. Although it won't work the other way - if you have the `@Override`, but don't implement the interface, you get a compile error.

Comment: Therefore I mentioned that this is only necessary if the interface also implements the method  @AlexSomai